Active Bandpass with "Tunable" F Using Potentiometer
I'm trying to construct a simple bandpass filter circuit using the multiple feedback topology with one op-amp (I'd like to leave out a dual-opamp approach for now). I'd like the center frequency to be adjustable using a potentiometer.
The problem is that simply replacing one R by a VR does not suffice: the interaction of the elements in the circuit is far more complex than that.
A possible approach is using a dual potentiometer, so we can adjust two of the Rs at the same time, and indeed this has gotten me quite far in the direction of a satisfying solution. After some experimentation, I've found that it makes sense to replace R1 and R3 with one dual VR (plus a pre-R each).
Consider this example using a dual 100 kΩ potentiometer:

Adjusting VR1 between 0..1000 Ω, and VR3 between 0..100000 Ω yields a center frequency of ~65..20000 Hz (with Q, by the way, being remarkably stable over the whole range).
That is pretty much exactly what I need (and I don't even need Q to be that constant).
Except: the two halves of a typical dual VR, of course, don't behave like that, but are designed to yield identical values unless modified. So the question is if there's a way to make one half range from 0..100K, and the other half to range from, say, 0..1 kΩ.
I'm aware that a parallel resistor can be a powerful tool in conjunction with a VR, being able to significantly alter the latter's behaviour. Using e.g. a 1 kΩ parallel resistor, I can make VR1 range from 0 to 1K as desired. However, even with a logarithmic potentiometer, the resulting taper is pretty much useless (as expected): after 50% of its rotation, the resulting R will already have reached 0.94 kΩ. Vice versa, the tuning between 0 and 0.5 kΩ is restricted to only the first ~18% rotation.
So my question is two-fold:
(1) Are there other ways of "taming" one half of the dual VR?, and...
(2) considering that I may have become too fixated on that approach -- what other options are there? I've experimented with selecting different pairs of R1/2/3 to be replaced by a dual VR, I've tried different (relative) sizes of C1 and C2, and considered the option of reverse-wiring one half of the VR, but to no avail (above solution remains my most successful one). However, considering the complex inter-relations of the elements, there might be combinations of parameters that are ideal but have so far gone unnoticed by me.

Are your goals to have a filter, or design and build a filter, because frankly, I'd be recommending a filter integrated circuit for a variety of reasons.

Do a simulation moving C1 and C2 off by a standard tolerance, and peek at your frequency response, to convince you.

My goal is to have a filter by building one myself -- I'd rather not call it "designing", as I'm quite happy using tried-and-tested classic designs, but the point, for me, is to learn and work on my skills. It's crucial to me to understand what exactly is going on. Using an off-the-rack solution won't provide such an opportunity.

PS: regarding tolerances... I know, the parts tend to do what they want rather than what the simulation thinks they should. But that is of no big concern in my situation. I'm happy with rough ballpark figures for now, and just use the simulation to make sure what I do makes at least some sense before trying it in real life.

As the two caps are equal in value exchange caps for resistors and resistors for caps to be able to use a dual pot to set the center frequency.

Frequency response with the resistors decreasing from 100k to 1k. Chosen Q=10 remains constant.


Brilliant, that was spot-on, and seems to solve the issue (says LTspice) -- I'll give it a real-world try soon, and will add a more detailed report when I get back from the breadboard.

For some pots, like the common through-panel ones, you can just buy 2 double ganged pots, one for each range, and then bend back the tabs which hold them together and swap the one "plate" out for the other and bend the tabs back.

Very elegant approach as well! I will keep it mind, for it might be useful in another situation.
